# why kjournald uses writes so much?

Tags: journaling

```
Total DISK READ: 1056.26 K/s | Total DISK WRITE: 9.20 M/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
 1055 be/4 root          0.00 B     11.64 M  0.00 %  1.99 % [kjournald]
 1054 be/4 root          0.00 B      9.72 M  0.00 %  1.70 % [kjournald]
 1053 be/4 root          0.00 B      5.21 M  0.00 %  0.73 % [kjournald]
 1056 be/4 root          4.00 K      2.77 M  0.00 %  0.39 % [kjournald]
 1082 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.34 % [flush-8:48]
 1078 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.33 % [flush-8:32]
 1080 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.09 % [flush-8:16]
  493 be/3 root          0.00 B   1128.00 K  0.00 %  0.04 % [jbd2/sda3-8]
 1081 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.01 % [flush-8:64]
 1079 be/4 root         16.00 K    228.00 K  0.00 %  0.01 % [flush-8:0]
 1126 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [kjournald]
 1125 be/0 root          0.00 B     56.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % [loop0]
 2974 be/4 nobody        4.00 K     12.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
 5506 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
  301 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      8.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
  311 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      8.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
  314 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
  332 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      8.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
24916 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
  347 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
  348 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
16741 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
  367 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
  368 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
  384 be/4 nobody        0.00 B     12.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
  394 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
  414 be/4 nobody        0.00 B     12.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
  421 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
  422 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      8.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
21049 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
29281 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
29289 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
 3517 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
29389 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
29390 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
29398 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
32207 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
  874 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      8.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
29562 be/4 nobody        0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd -k start -DSSL
```

kjournald writes 11.64 mb data and stuff. THe sum of ALL other writes are not that much. Also what is jbd2/sda3-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** see the real sum of all write from `iotop`.

1. `iotop` row number is limited by your terminal height, processes maybe push off the screen by other processes with more recent I/O activities.
2. Processes that wrote to disk then ended will not stay on the list. (eg. httpd spawn/fork process. Base on PID of `httpd`, I believe many of httpd child process exit already.)

Check size of httpd log files, I believe the size should show noticeable increase.

JBD2 : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBD2

Overview Quote from wikipedia:

> The Journaling Block Device (JBD) provides a filesystem-independent interface for filesystem journaling. ext3, ext4 and OCFS2 are known to use JBD. OCFS2 starting from linux 2.6.28 and ext4 use a fork of JBD called JBD2